# Command line to restart virtual machine (Virtual PC)

Tags: windows-7, command-line, microsoft-virtual-pc

Is there a way to restart a virtual machine running under Windows 7 Virtual PC from a command line? Basically, i want to do a soft restart, same thing the clicking on Ctrl+Alt+Del button achieves.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the `shutdown` command, something like

> shutdown /r /m \\ComputerName

Type

> shutdown /?

at the command prompt for a full list of options.

(It may be that you are working in the virtual machine and want to do CTRL-Alt-DEL, but the host is capturing the keypresses, and you are trying to get round this behaviour in a fancy way. You can use the Right ALT key with DEL.)

Comment: The `shutdown` command is, of course, not specific to VMs.

Answer (score 4):

`shutdown /i`

Will give you a GUI where you can add multiple remote machines to reboot.

For syntax and information see the Microsoft article [Restart or Shut Down a Remote Computer and Document the Reason](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc770416.aspx)

> 1. Type shutdown /i to display the Remote Shutdown dialog box
>      (Shutdown.exe).
> 2. Under Computers, click Add to enter computer names, or click Browse to open the Find Computers dialog box.
> 3. Under What do you want these computers to do, click Restart or Shut down.

Comment: Add 127.0.0.1 if you dont remember the name of the computer